# Split string and append to new string without the last element, til the stringlist is empty

Tags: c#, string, list, split

I want to split a string, get it to a list and then append all the items to a new string without the last element of the list. This should be done til the list is empty.

So lets say my splitted string list looks like this:

01

02

03

04

then I want my new list to look like this:

01.02.03

01.02

01

Splitting the string is no problem and making my first correct string. The problem is how I get the loop to "start over" without the last element, and continue doing this til the list is empty. This is how far I've come:

```
var separator = ".";
var listOfStrings = "01.02.03.04";
var separatedStringList = listOfStrings.Split(separator).ToList();
string newString;
foreach(var item in separatedStringList)
{
  if(separatedStringList.Last != item){
      newString += item;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do the following to get the list of strings.

```
var listOfStrings = "01.02.03.04";
var separatedStringList = listOfStrings.Split('.').ToList();
var list =
    Enumerable.Range(1, separatedStringList.Count - 1)
        .Select(i => string.Join(".", separatedStringList.Take(i)))
        .ToList();
foreach(var s in list) Console.WriteLine(s);
```

This will output

> 01
>
> 01.02
>
> 01.02.03

And if you want them in the oppisite order just throw in a `Reverse()` before the `ToList()`, or change the argument passed to `Take` from `i` to `separatedStringList.Count - i`.

Answer (score 2):

```
var listOfStrings = "01.02.03.04";
var arr = listOfStrings.Split(new char[] { '.' });        
List<string> results = new List<string>();

for (int i = 1; i < arr.Length; i++)
{
    var str = String.Join(".", arr.Reverse().Skip(i).Reverse());
    results.Add(str);
}
```

Edit:

```
for (int i = 1; i < arr.Length; i++)
{
    var str = String.Join(".", arr.Take(arr.Length - i));
    results.Add(str);
}
```

Comment: That's what i would have answered too, the foreach is just confusing in this case. A simple for loop is the way to go here.

Comment: `Reverse().Skip(i).Reverse()` is the same as `Take(arr.Length - i)`, but less efficient.

Answer (score 0):

You can use LINQ's `Take` method here:

```
for (int i = separatedStringList.Count - 1; i--; i > 0)
{
    newString = String.Join(".", separatedStringList.Take(i).ToArray());
    Console.WriteLine(newString);
}
```

I am not sure if you want separate strings or one spanning multiple lines (or maybe a list of strings?). My answer most probably won't solve you problem, but it might be a good starting point.

Comment: Why on earth doesn't LINQ have a `scan` function like F#'s, I'll never know : list |> Seq.scan "" (+) |> List.rev)

Comment: @AdamKewley I'm not familiar with F#, but I know some Haskell. And looking at the documentation for `scan`, I agree with you. The way I imagined it could be done is exactly as you posted :)

Answer (score 0):

Don't see any problem:

```
var separator = '.';
var listOfStrings = "01.02.03.04";
var separatedStringList = listOfStrings.Split(separator).ToList();
var result = new List<string>();

//take "01"
var temp = separatedStringList[0];

//add "01" to list
result.Add(temp);

if(separatedStringList.Count > 1)
{
    //loop through second till last 
    for(int i = 1; i < separatedStringList.Count - 1; i++)
    {
        //make temp "01.02" then "01.02.03"
        temp += "." + separatedStringList[i];

        //add temp to list
        result.Add(temp);
    }
}
```

For opposite direction:

```
var separator = '.';
var listOfStrings = "01.02.03.04";
var separatedStringList = listOfStrings.Split(separator).ToList();
var result = new string[separatedStringList.Count - 1];

var temp = separatedStringList[0];
result[result.Length - 1] = temp;

for (int i = 1; i < separatedStringList.Count - 1; i++)
{
    temp += "." + separatedStringList[i];
    result[result.Length - i - 1] = temp;
}
```